# SS2K5ALLPLATFORM Return error at Oracle Database 19c

Tags: sql, oracle, package, procedure

I am trying to move ms sql to oracle(migration). But I have error. I use SQL server Management 18 and Oracle Database 19c. I already connected to each other. This is my SS2K5ALLPLATFORM package;

```
create or replace PACKAGE SS2K5ALLPLATFORM AS 
                    FUNCTION StageCapture(projectId NUMBER, pluginClassIn VARCHAR2, projExists BOOLEAN:=FALSE, p_scratchModel BOOLEAN := FALSE) RETURN VARCHAR2;
                    FUNCTION amINewid(myc clob) return number; -- public function as called from sql
                    Function getPrecision(typein varchar2 , precisionin number, scalein number) return number; -- public function as called from sql
                    Function getnewscale(typein varchar2 , precisionin number, scalein number) return number; -- public function as called from sql
                    FUNCTION printUDTDef(basename VARCHAR2, p  NUMBER, s NUMBER,m NUMBER )  RETURN VARCHAR2; --public function used from sql                       
                    FUNCTION GetStatus(iid INTEGER) RETURN VARCHAR2;    END;
```

And this area give me error;

```
DECLARE
PROJECTID NUMBER;
PLUGINCLASSIN VARCHAR2(200);
PROJEXISTS BOOLEAN;
P_SCRATCHMODEL BOOLEAN;
v_Return VARCHAR2(200);
  BEGIN
    PROJECTID := NULL;
    PLUGINCLASSIN := NULL;
    PROJEXISTS := NULL;
    P_SCRATCHMODEL := NULL;

    v_Return := SS2K5ALLPLATFORM.STAGECAPTURE(
       PROJECTID => PROJECTID,
       PLUGINCLASSIN => PLUGINCLASSIN,
       PROJEXISTS => PROJEXISTS,
       P_SCRATCHMODEL => P_SCRATCHMODEL
      );
   /* Legacy output: 
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('v_Return = ' || v_Return);
      */ 
     :v_Return := v_Return;
      --rollback;  
     END;
```

And my error log is below.

```
Connecting to the database SqltoOracle.
ORA-06510: PL/SQL: işlenmemiş kullanıcı-tanımlı istisna
ORA-06512: konum "MIGRATIONS.SS2K5ALLPLATFORM",  satır 3313
ORA-01403: hiç veri bulunmadı
ORA-06512: konum "MIGRATIONS.SS2K5ALLPLATFORM",  satır 3280
ORA-06512: konum  satır 13
Capture:LogInfo Failed: [StageCapture Failed: [ORA-01403: hiç veri bulunmadı
 ORA-06512: konum "MIGRATIONS.SS2K5ALLPLATFORM",  satır 3280
 ] nSvrId: ] insert exception: ORA-04098: tetikleyici 'MIGRATIONS.STAGE_MIGRLOG_ID_TRG' 
 geçersiz ve yeniden doğrulamada başarısız oldu
 ORA-01403: hiç veri bulunmadı
 ORA-06512: konum "MIGRATIONS.SS2K5ALLPLATFORM",  satır 93
 ORA-06512: konum "MIGRATIONS.SS2K5ALLPLATFORM",  satır 3280 
 Process exited.
  Disconnecting from the database SqltoOracle.
```

Thank you your attention.

Comment: Can you translate the line that contains the exception to english? Most people here won't be able to read that.

Comment: One can use Google Translate from Turkish if desired. But ORA codes are usually pretty well documented by themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Various errors have been reported.

ORA-06510 means that there's user-defined exception in that code; it was raised, but it was never handled.

ORA-01403 is also here, and it means `NO_DATA_FOUND`. Maybe `SS2K5ALLPLATFORM.STAGECAPTURE` (which is called in that piece of code) raises that exception, but you didn't handle it. Something like this:

```
begin
  raise no_data_found;

-- this is missing:
exception
  when no_data_found then null;
end;
```

Comment: When i created migration project. It is creates automaticly by oracle db then i tried migration operation but i gives me that error. My database has one table and 3 datas. I gave all privileges for two side.